# Problem parsing Alexa json response in python to get value name

Tags: json, python-3.x, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I have the following intent passed to my handler:

```
"request": {
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.3af5c8c3-1d1f-4169-8ce8-fde1a99a7c8d",
    "timestamp": "2019-04-03T04:08:06Z",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "intent": {
        "name": "get_speeds",
        "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
        "slots": {
            "direction": {
                "name": "direction",
                "value": "inbound",
                "resolutions": {
                    "resolutionsPerAuthority": [
                        {
                            "authority": "amzn1.er-authority.echo-sdk.amzn1.ask.skill.e76bf13b-71ac-4a90-94d4-597aa597ae87.direction",
                            "status": {
                                "code": "ER_SUCCESS_MATCH"
                            },
                            "values": [
                                {
                                    "value": {
                                        "name": "inbound",
                                        "id": "a8e6fe5b9e68f30a146cefebaa7edcc3"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
                "source": "USER"
            }
        }
    },
    "dialogState": "COMPLETED"
}
```

I want to extract the actual value, not the utterance, e.g., the value name, in this case, "inbound". I've tried this and various similar iterations (the prints are for debugging):

```
    slots = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots
    resolutions = slots["direction"].resolutions
    print(resolutions)
    print(resolutions["resolutions_per_authority"])
    direction = resolutions["resolutions_per_authority"][0]["values"][0]["value"]["name"]
    session_attr = handler_input.attributes_manager.session_attributes
```

I've also tried the same with "resolutionsPerAuthority" which is the JSON that is passed, but apparently not what comes out to my program, as the log has:

```
04:08:07
{'resolutions_per_authority': [{'authority': 'amzn1.er-authority.echo-sdk.amzn1.ask.skill.e76bf13b-71ac-4a90-94d4-597aa597ae87.direction',

04:08:07
'status': {'code': 'ER_SUCCESS_MATCH'},

04:08:07
'values': [{'value': {'id': 'a8e6fe5b9e68f30a146cefebaa7edcc3',

04:08:07
'name': 'inbound'}}]}]}

04:08:07
'Resolutions' object is not subscriptable
```

This is the error I keep getting with all my approaches: 'Resolutions' object is not subscriptable. Can someone help me with how to extract the canonical slot values? I need to do the same thing for several other intents, but I figure if I can get this one working, it will be a model for the others.

Comment: It doesn't appear like you've posted the full json. `'resolutions_per_authority'` doesn't appear in the example dictionary you posted.

Comment: That's one of the things puzzling me! The skill i/o display in the Alexa test page has what's shown above. There's a resolutionsPerAuthority but NOT a resolutions_per_authority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already pointed out, your problem was that you treated the resolution object as it was subscriptable, accessing it via

```
resolutions.resolutions_per_authority[0].values[0].value
```

is the right way to obtain it.

It may be helpful to point out that, in case of multiple matches, Alexa will return the resolutions in the order of the most likely to match the user intent.

This code snippet iterates the slots and return a python dictionary with just the keys to know if it was validated and the id of the matched value:

```
from ask_sdk_model.slu.entityresolution import StatusCode

@staticmethod
def get_slot_values(filled_slots):
    """Return slot values with additional info."""
    slot_values = {}
    logger.info("Filled slots: {}".format(filled_slots).replace("\n", "\r"))

    for key, slot_item in six.iteritems(filled_slots):
        name = slot_item.name
        try:
            status_code = slot_item.resolutions.resolutions_per_authority[0].status.code

            if status_code == StatusCode.ER_SUCCESS_MATCH:
                slot_values[name] = {
                    "synonym": slot_item.value,
                    "resolved": slot_item.resolutions.resolutions_per_authority[0].values[0].value.__dict__,  # to make it JSON serializable
                    "is_validated": True,
                }
            elif status_code == StatusCode.ER_SUCCESS_NO_MATCH:
                slot_values[name] = {
                    "synonym": slot_item.value,
                    "resolved": slot_item.value,
                    "is_validated": False,
                }
            else:
                pass
        except (AttributeError, ValueError, KeyError, IndexError, TypeError) as e:
            # for BUILT-IN intents, there are no resolutions, but the value is specified
            if slot_item.value is not None and slot_item.value != 'NONE':
                slot_values[name] = {
                    "synonym": slot_item.value,
                    "resolved": slot_item.value,
                    "is_validated": True,
                }
            else:
                logger.info("SLOT {} UNRESOLVED".format(name))
                slot_values[name] = {
                    "synonym": slot_item.value,
                    "resolved": slot_item.value,
                    "is_validated": False,
                }
    return slot_values
```

where `filled_slots = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots`

Answer (score 2):

OK, I finally located a python example that uses the object-oriented version of the relatively new SDK, as I am. The example is the python version of Amazon's [PetMatch](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-python-petmatch/blob/master/lambda/py/lambda_function.py) example.

Based on that, the following is working:

```
slots = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots
direction = slots["direction"].resolutions.resolutions_per_authority[0].values[0].value.name
```

I'm still looking to understand better HOW it works, but at least it's working, and may also help someone else. I find that with Alexa examples and documentation, there is a ton out there, but it's not well organized and the api keeps changing, so some of what you find turns out to be obsolete.